# IE6 PNG fix in Spoon.net IE6 no longer working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, iepngfix

I am using the following PNG fix for IE6 but it does not appear to be working for me:

http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/

It was working previously but i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

I am working in a .NET environment and all of my JS is referenced like so:

```
<%= Html.Script("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js")%>
<%= Html.Script("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js")%>

<%= Html.Script("~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery.colorbox-min.js")%>   
<%= Html.Script("~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery.jqtransform.js")%>      
<%= Html.Script("~/Scripts/Plugins/jqPrint.js")%>
<%= Html.Script("~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery.print.colorbox.js")%> 
<%= Html.Script("~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery.mousewheel.min.js")%>
<%= Html.Script("~/Scripts/Plugins/jScrollPane-1.2.3.min.js")%>
<%= Html.Script("~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery.tools.min.js")%>

<%= Html.Script("~/Scripts/icis.dashboard.js")%>
<%= Html.Script("~/Scripts/icis.pricereport.js")%>
<%= Html.Script("~/Scripts/PriceAssessment/tooltip.js")%>   

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="../../Scripts/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js" defer="defer"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="../../Scripts/DD_PNG_listing.js" defer="defer"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

However the PNG fix does not appear to be working.  All 24bit PNG are exhibiting the IE6 grey background.

Conditional comments do appear to be working for CSS though:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/styles/icis.dashboard.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/>
<![endif]-->
```

My PNg list file is like this:

```
//------------------------------------------- set up string of CSS selectors
//---------- IMPORTANT: each line (*except the last*) must end with a comma

var listing = ''

listing += '.dark_overlay,'
listing += '#icis_dashboard #header h1,'
listing += '#icis_dashboard .widget,'
listing += '#icis_dashboard .widget .fly_out,'
listing += '#icis_dashboard .widget .inline_list li,'
listing += '#icis_dashboard .w_price_history .tabs li,'
listing += '#icis_dashboard .w_price_history .tabs li a,'
listing += '#icis_dashboard .w_price_history .tabs li a span,'
listing += '#icis_dashboard .ui-datepicker-trigger,'
listing += '#cboxLoadingOverlay,'
listing += '#cboxLoadingGraphic,'
listing += '#cboxClose,'
listing += '.cboxIE #cboxTopLeft,'
listing += '.cboxIE #cboxTopCenter,'
listing += '.cboxIE #cboxTopRight,'
listing += '.cboxIE #cboxBottomLeft,'
listing += '.cboxIE #cboxBottomCenter,'
listing += '.cboxIE #cboxBottomRight,'
listing += '.cboxIE #cboxMiddleLeft,'
listing += '.cboxIE #cboxMiddleRight,'
listing += '#dialog_head ul li,'
listing += '.jqTransformRadio,'
listing += '.jqTransformRadioWrapper a.jqTransformChecked,'
listing += 'a.jqTransformCheckbox,'
listing += 'span.jqTransformCheckboxWrapper a.jqTransformChecked,'
listing += '.jqTransformSelectWrapper,'
listing += '.jqTransformSelectWrapper  a.jqTransformSelectOpen,'
listing += '#dialog_head ul li'

//------------------------------------------- call function

DD_belatedPNG.fix(listing)
```

I would use the standalone but have no registry access to turn conditional comments on for the IE6 standalone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah.

This is because i am in a .NET MVC environment and was fixed with this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="<%= Url.Content("~") %>Scripts/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js" defer="defer"></script>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="<%= Url.Content("~") %>Scripts/DD_PNG_listing.js" defer="defer"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```